# Order of Controller Lifecycle Hook onInit() in sap.m.NavContainer

Tags: lifecycle, sapui5

Given I have a view *App.view.xml* which includes the view *Login.view.xml*:

```
<mvc:View
        xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
        xmlns="sap.m"
        displayBlock="true"
        controllerName="App">
    <Shell showLogout="false">
        <NavContainer id="loginNavContainer">
            <mvc:XMLView id="loginView" viewName="Login" />
        </NavContainer>
    </Shell>
</mvc:View>
```

When I add a breakpoint to the lifecycle hooks `App.view.controller.onInit()` and `Login.view.controller.onInit()` I would expect that the `onInit()` from the App controller is called before the `onInit()` of the Login controller.
But it's the other way round. The lifecycle hook `onInit()` of the Login controller is invoked before the `onInit()` of the App controller.

The App view is instantiated/created by sap.ui.core.UIComponent.

Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onInit == onAfterInit
```

Fired from `sap.ui.core.mvc.View::_initCompositSupport`

The view and its content is created inside the init-method of the view. After that stuff is done, the *on**After**Init* of the view is fired.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So if I want to publish an event in the Login controller and the App controller subscribes to this event, in which lifecycle hooks would you add the event bus methods?